# GKE nodes binding to a gateway

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gateway, gke-networking

I'm trying to route nodes managed by GKE to a gateway so each one of the nodes will eventually have the same IP. The reason is to allow, that static gateway IP only, to access my clients firewall.

I didn't find a solution on Google Kubernetes Engine, can anyone think of a way of doing that, with my GKE nodes?

[image: This is an image that describe the desired solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) in GCP to allow GKE outbound connections through a single external IP address, therefore you can whitelist that public IP address in your Firewall device. You can check the next [link](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example#introduction) for how to configure Cloud NAT in GKE

Comment: In order to use kubectl commands, you need to have access to GKE master endpoint, if the Master endpoint is a [private endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#access_to_the_cluster_endpoints), it can only be reachable from the same VPC and region as the GKE cluster.

Comment: This means that only resources from Google can reach it, as a workaround, you could use a [bastion VM](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#bastion) instance to reach it from on-prem. You access the bastion VM from on-prem and then from that VM you can run kubectl commands.

Comment: However if your GKE master endpoint is public, you must install kubectl and you can access kubectl commands with [authentication for kubectl](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#authentication)